# It is possible to work with github entirely online?

Tags: github, github-for-windows

Simply put, can I use github online rather than ever having to download the program for windows. It appears to be much easier than downloading git or the github application. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can if you like. Github supports online editing and commit. But I don't think it's convenient since you cannot compile, run and debug your codes, and easy to lost your work when you close your browser without save.

Answer (score 1):

You lose a lot of power by giving up the command line, but you can certainly do most routine tasks in the cloud. You can do some [limited editing](https://help.github.com/articles/editing-files-in-your-repository) and repository tasks directly on GitHub, or hook into your GitHub repository with a cloud-based IDE like [Cloud9](https://c9.io/), [CodeEnvy](https://codenvy.com/), or other similar services.